# Google scraping results

Tags: php, curl, proxy, screen-scraping

I need to get the google top 10 results for some keyword but I know that google dont's allow that. How to do that. WIth some proxy, script... I'm only need the URL's of top 10 sites for some keyword. Is there any way to get this results?

Comment: some php code for getting url's from google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google Custom Search API would be the correct interface to perform this task: 
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/

Comment: Yes but it have a limit for 5000 query per day :(

Comment: @JohnySource, buy 10 IP's and you have 50.000 :)

Comment: It's free for up to 100 queries a day, but you can pay for up to 10,000 queries a day, ("However, you will be billed for all additional requests at the rate of $5 per 1000 queries, for up to 10,000 queries per day"). <br />

Comment: @speeves Are you sure custumsearch is the correct interface? AFAIK it only allows searching predefined sites, not the whole web.